# O que é o arquivo MERGE_MSG.swp?

Tags: git, github, merge

Ao executar o comando de *merge* da minha *branch* em outra. Ocorreu o seguinte alerta:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conforme a própria descrição da imagem. O alerta é exibido por causa que o arquivo `.MERGE_MSG.swp` também está sendo editado por outra pessoa ou alguma edição no arquivo gerou conflito com a versão do arquivo em minha máquina.

Irei deletá-lo da minha máquina para baixar a versão atual da *master*. Mas antes gostaria de uma definição sobre o arquivo. Qual a função dele e pra que serve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este é um arquivo temporário do vim. [Aqui você tem a documentação deste tipo de arquivo](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/recover.html).